# R - what command to generate confusion matrix using as input results from rpart() and predict()?

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

What command should I use in R to perform a confusion matrix after having used `rpart()` and `predict()` commands to generate a prediction model?

```
# Grow tree
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(activity ~ ., method="class", data=train.data)

printcp(fit) # display the results
plotcp(fit) # visualize cross-validation results
summary(fit) # detailed summary of splits

# Prune the tree (in my case is exactly the same as the initial model)
pfit <- prune(fit, cp=0.10) # from cptable
pfit <- prune(fit,cp=fit$cptable[which.min(fit$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"])

# Predict using the test dataset
pred1 <- predict(fit, test.data, type="class")

# Show re-substitution error
table(train.data$activity, predict(fit, type="class"))

# Accuracy rate
sum(test.data$activity==pred1)/length(pred1)
```

I would like to summarise in a clear way True Positives, False Negatives, False Positives and True Negatives. It would be great also to have in the same matrix Sensitivity, Specificity, Positive Predictive Value and Negative Predictive Value.

[image: Relationships among terms]
Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity

Comment: Maybe you can get predictions from both models in new variables and make table(DF$rpart,DF$predict) where DF is you data frame in analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `predict()` method, with your fit and the original data frame, like so:

```
pred = predict(train.fit, newdata, type = "vector")
newdata$pred = as.vector(pred)
newdata$prediction = activities[newdata$pred]

tab = table (newdata$prediction, newdata$activity)
print(tab)
```

In the example above, the rpart model predicts an activity (a factor variable).  `pred` is numeric, with values corresponding to the levels of the factor.  `activities = sort(unique(data$activity))` corresponds to the default factor mapping.

Comment: I usually like to add on with
confmat <- table(newdata$classes, predicted_classes)

accuracy = (confmat[1] + confmat[5] + confmat[9]) / sum(confmat)

confmat
sprintf("Accuracy is %f", accuracy)